# Program gets slower when filling chart

Tags: performance, memory, charts

I made a little program in Visual Basic that counts products when it comes through a laser.
Every second the chart fills a data point and says if the output is high or low and makes a chart on it so we can see when there wasn't a flow at a certain point in time.

After approximately 10 hours the program becomes slow because it registers every second and puts it in the chart. The chart runs on a form timer.

Is there a way to make it faster or clear the cache and continue filling the chart?
When the product is finished I press a button and then the chart is saved as a .jpg and I clear the chart and after that it is functional again. Time of the production takes up to 20 hours.

Comment: We would probably need to see some of your code around adding/clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

1 datapoint every second for 20 hours is 72000 datapoints. You **will** have performance issues displaying and updating 70K datapoints once every second notwithstanding the fact that this is in VB.

You may want to rethink how you're doing the graphing. Do you really need to show all 70K datapoints live to the operator? What if you showed only the last 2K points? You don't have to throw away the earlier data, just keep it elsewhere in a csv file, or an access database, or anything else (ideally in a MSSQL Express or a MySQL DB), just not the graph object.

If you *do* need to show graphs for the entire run, think about averaging. What if you rolled up sets of 50 points into 1 average data-point? Again you don't have to throw away actual data, just keep it elsewhere.

At the end of your run, you can click the report button to generate a graph from all 70000 stored points to export/store as jpg. But this is a one time thing and even if it takes a while - it wouldn't be that critical an issue.

Comment: Many thanks for ur reply! You let me think of different solutions. It's the best way for the operator to see what happend the last few hours, but maby the last 10000 data points is also an solution. How is it possible to show the last 10000 data points without throwing data away? After the product is finished the data is printed on a document and I need all the data. Many thanks for thinking with me =)

Comment: Store your data in an MS Access database. You can query for the last X datapoints to show on your graph.

Comment: Ok I will try this, but how do I store every data point before 10000 each second?